# joining a text file in groups of 3 entries

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file like this:

```
X0122
Yellow Car
$1200
YK321
Black Car
$400
BZ321132
Red Boat
$2344
```

every line is separated by a `\n`

I want to join every 3 elements in a line separated by `;`. So, the file will be converted into this:

```
X0122;Yellow Car;$1200
YK321;Black Car;$400
BZ321132;Red Boat;$2344
```

How do I do that on unix?

Note: the files may contain accented letters like á, ó, ã and single quotes and are coded in "UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines", like the command `file` say about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [paste](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
$ paste -sd';;\n' file
X0122;Yellow Car;$1200
YK321;Black Car;$400
BZ321132;Red Boat;$2344
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?";":RS'
```

Output:

```
X0122;Yellow Car;$1200
YK321;Black Car;$400
BZ321132;Red Boat;$2344
```

Explanation: Depending on the line number, the output record separator is set either to a semicolon or to a newline.